# Is it possible to install a virtual Audio output device (the hardware itself does not exist) on Ubuntu and get audio data?

Tags: google-chrome, audio-recording

I want to set the audio output destination of Headless Chrome to a virtual audio output device and get audio data from the virtual audio output device. (On Ubuntu)

It is a question.

・ How do I install a virtual Audio output device on Ubuntu?
・ Can I install multiple virtual audio output devices on Ubuntu?
・ Can Headless Chrome output sound to a virtual audio device?

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to record an audio stream played from web app? Why python tag? Why selenium? Please [edit] your question to make it less unclear.

Comment: I don't want to record an audio stream played from web app. I want to record an audio stream played from virtual Audio output devices. for example, by python scripts.

Comment: If there is a virtual audio device file (Linux audio device driver), it should be possible. So I asked a question.

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219769/348533

Comment: @cmak.fr Thank you!!!